# C Function to leave only unique nodes in singly linked list

Tags: c, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm having an issue: in a function, program needs to compare two nodes and delete one of them if the node values are the same (example: A -> B -> B -> C  >>>  A -> B -> C). In a few words: it have to leave only unique nodes.

Steps that I've done: created list from data given in data file and it prints out perfectly. Now I'm struggling comparing two nodes.

Steps that I'm thinking of doing: Put two nodes values in two different variables, then comparing those two and if latest node is equal to previous, delete the latest and somehow link previous node to next node. Then the cycle goes all over again.

Question: How do I compare node with further one?

Here's the code that I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 255

struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *next;
} *head = NULL;

int create(FILE **data){
    char read[LENGTH];
    printf("Write data file name: ");
    scanf("%s", read);
    *data = fopen (read, "r");

    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading given file.");
    }

    return 0;
}

int put_Symbols_into_list(FILE *data) {

    struct node *new_node, *current;
    char c;

    printf("Data given: ");
    while (!feof(data)){
        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        c = fscanf(data, "%s", &new_node -> info);
        printf("%s ", &new_node -> info);

        if (head == NULL){
            head = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        } else {
            current -> next = new_node;
            current = new_node;
        }
    }

}

int delete_Same_Symbols() {

}

int main() {
    FILE *data;
    struct node *n;
    create(&data);
    put_Symbols_into_list(data);
    delete_Same_Symbols();
    //display_List(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Rimantas Radžiūnas There is no sense to discuss how to remove duplicates because at first you have to write correctly the function that adds nodes to the list. At present your function is invalid.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? Where did I do wrong?

Comment: You have to set data member next of the last added node to NULL.

Comment: Hi Vlad, after thinking, I couldn't find a incorrectly written code, as I'm only learning lists. Could you post how that code should look?

Comment: You have to set to NULL data member next of the last added node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way of remove duplicates is the following:

```
1. Sort the list
2. Run through the list once deleting any adjacent duplicates.
```

Whether this solution works for you depends on whether your data can be ordered.

Comment: You read the title but not the question, he wants to know how to compare the nodes.

Comment: Yes, for a linked list. 1) takes time O(nlog(n)) and 2) takes time O(n). The alternative is  to loop through the list and have a subloop that searches the list for duplicates. That will take time O(n^2).

Comment: @iharob I interpret "How do I compare node with further one?" to mean that the problem was to compare a node with one further along. If you sort first, then you only need to compare adjacent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the list from head to end and maintain a Hash table. 
For every element,check whether value is in the hash table: if yes, remove the node; else put value in the hash table.

Time Complexity: O(n) on average (assuming that hash table access time is O(1) on average).

Comment: How, on any level, does this help to answer: **Question: How do I compare node with further one?**

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the function that will remove the duplicates.
Assuming that your code is working fine and that the **info** is an **int value**
Note that if info is a string you will need strcmp function instead of `head->info == info.`

```
int exist(NODE *head, int info) {
    while (head && head->info != info) // strcmp(info,head->info) != 0
        head = head->next;

    return head->info == info; // strcmp(info,head->info)
}

void removeDuplicates(NODE **phead, int info) {
    NODE *tmp = *phead;
    while (tmp->info != info) // strcmp(info,head->info) != 0
        tmp = tmp->next;
    NODE *tmp1 = tmp->next;
    tmp->info = tmp1->info; // strcpy(tmp->info,tmp1->info)
    tmp->next = tmp1->next;
    free(tmp1);
}
```